# How to select multiple table cell tags with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

**UPDATE**: This problem is when I create this table over an **about:blank** page and use the console in Chrome. Trying it in JSFiddle works as expected.

**UPDATE2**: Disregard this. As @Mike C commented, I wasn't loading jQuery, and Chrome dev tools have a built in function called '$'. In other words, it wasn't working because the Chrome dev tools didn't know I was writing jQuery. My mistake. 
Thank you all for your help.

This is simply straightforward. I have something like this:

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >1</td>
            <td >2</td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td> 
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I try to get all the `<td>`, with `$("td")`, I only get the **first** element, while using `document.getElementsByTag("td")` I get **all** the elements.

In the jQuery documentation, it says that `$("tagName")` is enough to get the tag element, but when I try it, only returns the first element.

Why does this happen? Is there a jQuery **selector** that has the same behaviour than `getElementsByTag`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("td")` should return all the cells. What are you doing exactly?

Comment: $("td") should return all the td tags.

Comment: I would think it should work like you described. maybe try $("td").each(function(){});

Comment: Please make a fiddle demonstrating this. Documentation doesn't lie (well... sometimes..), something else is going on.

Comment: Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5npm2a2k/)

Comment: `$('td')` returns an array of jQuery objects (not DOM nodes). You'll need to show us how you're using this to expect further assistance.

Comment: I'm using `$('td')`, and I'm just testing the behaviour. 
I'm creating this html over an **about:blank** page in _Chrome_, and then running this code over the console.
Funny how this works: If I do the same in JSFiddle, it works.

Comment: Show what you are actually doing...

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery into your `about:blank` page? The Chrome dev tools have a built in function called `$` which is basically a wrapper for `document.querySelector`

Comment: @MikeC damn... Never thought that would be the case.
This explains a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that depends on what you are doing, but still a simple demo.

**My Approach:**

**1)** Gave `.tableTd` class to `<table>` in your HTML.

**2)** Selected all `td's` inside that class.

> Reason of not using `$("table td")` is there may also be different tables on same page which we do not want to target.

```js
$(".tableTd td").css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1" class="tableTd">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >1</td>
            <td >2</td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td> 
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the one Down vote for? I would like to know. So that i can know my mistake. Thank You!

Comment: I actually want to get the multiple `<td>`

Don't know who downvoted you, though.

Comment: So try to do as above approach i gave. If you stuck somewhere feel free to ask. Through above approach you can get all `td's` inside your table that has class `class="tableTd"`.

Comment: Didn't work, but I already detected the issue. Your code works perfectly (It was because the page wasn't reading jQuery, as @Mike C mentioned above). Thanks for your help.

PS: I hate the "post when 'Enter' ".

Answer (score 1):

You understood the concept correctly. But you need to iterate through `each` function to get all corresponding elements.

```
$("td").each(function()
{
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/fgoed4rv/1/

Comment: In the end, it was a (lack of) jQuery reference issue in the blank page I was working on. 
Tried your code, and works perfectly. Thanks for the help